# How can I return html with CSS classes from angular function in the HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this list element where I call function with `[innerHTML]` which returns html elements and it is working, if I want some part of that html to be bolded. In this case the text from the - `difference.hours` will be bolded.

**HTML**

```
 <li class="list-group-item" [innerHTML]="getRemainingAppointmentDate(appointment.time_remaining)"></li>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
return `Hours: <strong>${difference.hours}</strong>`;
```

But i can't figure it out how can i give style to the elements.
For example if i try

```
return `Hours: <span class='red'>${difference.hours}</span>`;
```

then the given class is not applied to the returned text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues here

1. If you're using default change detection strategy, binding a function to a property like `[innerHTML]=...` would trigger the function for each CD cycle. That could be too many times that might potentially affect the app performance.
2. There are better ways set the CSS dynamically rather than to rely on `[innerHTML]`. It is better not to rely too heavily on `[innerHTML]` since it is relatively restricted. Eg. you need to explicitly tell Angular to trust the HTML using `DomSanitizer`'s `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` function.

Rather you could use `[ngClass]`. And since you haven't provided much information, I'll make following aussumptions:

- This is in a loop using `*ngFor` directive.
- Instead of making the function `remainingAppointmentDate()` return an HTML string, make it return a boolean based on the same condition.

Controller

```js
appointments.forEach(appointment => {
  if(this.remainingAppointmentDate(appointment.time_remaining)) {
    appointment.ending = true;
  } else {
    appointment.ending = false;
  }
});
```

Template

```html
<li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="appointment.ending ? 'red' : 'normal'"></li>
```

CSS selectors

```css
.red {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: red;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you need to decide the class for each passing second, you'd better make the conditional boolean RxJS observable and use `async` pipe in the template to update it.

#### Update: Working example

Here is the working example included in the comments: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-momentjs-rxfvou?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

And here is a screenshot of the output at the time of execution:

[image]

Comment: Hello Michael,Thanks for your reply. U understood everything except the first part, how you mean that innerHTML will trigger the function o nevery CD cycle? What you mean by  CD cycle ?

Comment: @andrej.boshkoski1: CD cycle is change detection cycle. Angular keeps the DOM updated by monitoring the controller's state. It's a broad topic to discuss here. You could start [here](https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/). In brief, the DOM will be refreshed for each state change. And in [default change detection strategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) the DOM will be refreshed for each state change in controller. So the function `remainingAppointmentDate()` will be triggered for each change in controller's state.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I had prfevious one setInterval in ngOnit where i was reloading the page but now i get - Expression has changed after it was checked - how can i run every appointmant_date in separete setInterval ?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, the better way would be rely on RxJS observables to update the value based on a interval (eg. using [`timer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer)) and update it in the template using the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe.

Comment: I am not so good with rxjs.Can you please provide example code ?

Comment: I don't know how shooild i implement that all with my moment.js function, my objects and the rxjs timer...

Comment: Also, i saw the example for the timer and i putted in the OnINit method the following code: const numbers = timer(3000, 1000);
   numbers.subscribe(x => x); after that again my function - getRemainingAppointmentDate is called, why setInterval re renders my function every time? and after some time i get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. error

Comment: @andrej.boshkoski1: I'm not currently in a position to provide a full fledged example. If you still want I could try to come up with one after few hours.

Comment: @andrej.boshkoski1: It took a while but [here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-momentjs-rxfvou?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I've hard coded the dates for illustration. Please adjust the dates and times accd. to your zone to see the CSS applied. Also the `async` pipe isn't required since we aren't trying to display an observable in the template. I'm updating the `ending` property every 1 sec using RxJS `timer`. Bear in mind it might hit performance if there are too many dates in the array.

Comment: In case if weren't able to trigger the other CSS [here is my output](https://i.imgur.com/seO5MbX.jpg) at the time of writing this comment.